# Unknown usages of functions in source code of predict.naiveBayes method in e1071 package

Tags: r

I don't understand, how method *predict.naiveBayes* works, if there are two misspelled usages of functions, i.e., **isnumeric[attribs[v]]** and **islogical[attribs[v]]**.

In my opinion, there should be **is.numeric(attribs[v])** and **is.logical(attribs[v])**, respectively.

Code below:

```
...
L <- sapply(1:nrow(newdata), function(i) {
    ndata <- newdata[i, ]
        L <- log(object$apriori) + apply(log(sapply(seq_along(attribs),
            function(v) {
                nd <- ndata[attribs[v]]
                if (is.na(nd)) rep(1, length(object$apriori)) else {
                  prob <- if (isnumeric[attribs[v]]) {
                    msd <- object$tables[[v]]
                    msd[, 2][msd[, 2] <= eps] <- threshold
                    dnorm(nd, msd[, 1], msd[, 2])
                  } else object$tables[[v]][, nd + islogical[attribs[v]]]
                  prob[prob <= eps] <- threshold
                  prob
                }
            })), 1, sum)
        if (type == "class")
            L
        else {
            ## Numerically unstable:
            ##            L <- exp(L)
            ##            L / sum(L)
            ## instead, we use:
            sapply(L, function(lp) {
                1/sum(exp(L - lp))
            })
        }
    })
...
```

Everything works fine, when I am using naive Bayes classifier from package, but it is rather strange, due to these inconsistencies. Can anyone explain me my doubts?

Answer (score 1):

Just two lines above your code excerpt there is basically what you expect:

```
isnumeric <- sapply(newdata, is.numeric)
islogical <- sapply(newdata, is.logical)
```

That is, `isnumeric` and `islogical` are not functions, they are validly defined logical vectors.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now. I did not notice that before, while glimpsing through the code.

Comment: Another think that you could have tried is running `isnumeric` and `e1071:::isnumeric` (in case the function is hidden) because perhaps there is indeed such function, defined in a nonstandard way. That's faster and easier than examining the code.